# Trigger a multibranch pipeline when there is a change in files in specific folder

Tags: jenkins, triggers, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline, polling

I want to run a multibranch pipeline when some files in a folder are pushed to BitBucket . I have tried with polling ignores commits to certain paths. But pipeline is not triggering . Can anyone help to solve the issue. How the path should be exactly specified inside included region of polling ignores commits to certain paths.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following `Jenkinsfile` in a Git repo that contains `1.txt` and `2.txt`:

```groovy
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        
        stage('1.txt in changelog') {
            when {
                // see https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#built-in-conditions
                changelog '1.txt'
            }
            steps {
                echo '1.txt in changelog'
            }
        }
 
        stage('2.txt in changelog') {
            when {
                changelog '2.txt'
            }
            steps {
                echo '2.txt in changelog'
            }
        }
        
        stage('1.txt in changeset') {
            when {
                changeset '1.txt'
            }
            steps {
                echo '1.txt in changeset'
            }
        }
 
        stage('2.txt in changeset') {
            when {
                changeset '2.txt'
            }
            steps {
                echo '2.txt in changeset'
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

After changing and pushing `2.txt` the Console Output of an according Multibranch Pipeline project showed:

```
...
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (1.txt in changelog)
Stage "1.txt in changelog" skipped due to when conditional
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (2.txt in changelog)
[Pipeline] echo
2.txt in changelog
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (1.txt in changeset)
Stage "1.txt in changeset" skipped due to when conditional
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (2.txt in changeset)
[Pipeline] echo
2.txt in changeset
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

The same applies to creation of `2.txt` but *not* to deletion of it.